# What is the best way of managing keyboard input in Android NativeActivity?

Tags: android, android-ndk, keyboard

I'm having problems using the keyboard in my application which is a **pure native application** (based on the `native-activity sample` provided in the Android NDK).

I have this Java code to show the keyboard:

```
mApplicationActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(mTextEdit != null)
            mTextEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);     
        mTextEdit = new EditText(mApplicationActivity);

        InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) mApplicationActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mTextEdit.setText(mTextEditValue);
        mEditTextLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mEditTextLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        mEditTextLayoutParams.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        mTextEdit.setLayoutParams(mEditTextLayoutParams);
        mTextEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTextEdit.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);

        mApplicationActivity.addContentView(mTextEdit, mEditTextLayoutParams);

        mTextEdit.bringToFront();
        mTextEdit.setSelection(mTextEdit.getText().length());
        mTextEdit.requestFocus();

        m.showSoftInput(mTextEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    }
});
```

I detect the input changes using the textWatcher to notify my C++ code and update the OpenGL UI. It seems to work properly in my Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2, but today I had a Nexus 4 with Android 4.2.2 and I can't remove the text I write.

So I'm wondering what is the best way to handle keyboard input assuming that:

- I render my own UI using OpenGL, the EditText is outside the screen.
- Using key events is a bad idea (as explained here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42904 "It does not work correctly with gesture input, or with voice input, or with toggle input, or any new inventive input method developers may come up with in the future.")

I would also consider if I could put the Java EditText over my OpenGL, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Here's the textWatcher code:

```
TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {  
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Call to C++ code 
            SendChangedText(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: textwathcer is the way to go can you show the code for mtextwatcher??

Comment: Yes, I have added it to the question. It has nothing special, just a call to my C++ code to update the UI. Debugging I have noticed that the textwatcher events are not called at all when pressing backspace on Android 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Im also using NativeActivity for my projects. Key event approach -

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) { ... }
```

worked for me only at beginning until one day, under 4.4 there was bug where backspace (delete) key event was not sent to event handler at all. As it seems its known bug of basic android keyboard. So i shifted from raw key-down handling to 'hidden EditText' solution.

Hidden EditText gives you way to get rid of bugs and to handle predictive input. To do so you need to implement your own InputConnectionWrapper (or it also can be BaseInputConnection). Inside EditText override onCreateInputConnection:

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {

    // We set manual input connection to catch all keyboard interaction
    return new MyInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs), true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    return true;
}
```

And now we are able to catch a lot of input events inside:

```
class MyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

public MyInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
    super(target, mutable);
}

@Override
public boolean setComposingText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "setComposingText " + text);
    return super.setComposingText(text, newCursorPosition);
}

@Override
public boolean commitText(CharSequence text, int newCursorPosition)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "commitText " + text);
    return super.commitText(text, newCursorPosition);
}

@Override
public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
}


@Override
public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {       
    if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DELETE!");
    }

    return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
}

}
```

See InputConnectionWrapper class for more info. As i understand the only way to capture all events from software keyboard is to override all methods provided by this interface.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this, but if you have more details, I'd appreciate it -- how do you create a hidden EditText over a NativeActivity's surface? For example if I get a window handle and start drawing to it with Vulkan, how would I also create a View on that window?